# Logitech K400+ not doing Tap-to-Click on Trackpad

Tags: touchpad, logitech, tap-to-click

Trackpad on Logitech K400+ wireless keyboard no longer clicks anything when the trackpad is tapped... (tap to click).

This used to work but suddenly stopped. Not sure if this was a mix of Ubuntu + kernel update or not, but didn't work after reinstall either...

Comment: BTW [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/612499/111181) might useful, if you suffer from unintentional zooming with Logitech K400.

Answer (score 16):

I've been struggling to find an answer to why the trackpad on my Logitech K400+ stopped doing Touch-To-Click...

I stumbled across the solution the other day and thought it would be useful to record it here for others...

Basically, all you need to do is to hold the function key (next to super), and click the left mouse button... If it doesn't work first time, try a couple more... Sorted :)

Comment: Interestingly, it also allows for multi-functions of alt and alt-gr... In Chrome, alt+left/right still nav forward or back a page, but the fun one is that alt-gr+left/right arrow does scroll first if page is scrollable, then nav :)

Comment: omg thanks rob for this answer. I use a macbook pro with this keyboard and it suddenly stopped. I used your trick. Hold the FN key and click a couple of times. Also tried it with the windows key next to it. One of the 2 did the trick

Comment: Thanks bro, worked like a charm +1

Comment: This works on windows as well!! Must be a KB thing. So odd! Thanks I thought the trackpad is broken, but it work fine.